# Android webview, responsive web page is not shown properly in some devices

Tags: android, webview

I've developed an app with a webview to show some links when user requests them, without opening an external web browser.

The problem is that those links are shown properly in native browser and *only* some SDK versions of webview, not all of them

For example, it is right in 5.1.1 but wrong in 4.4.4

This is right (Sony Z1 with 5.1.1):

[image]

This is wrong (Nexus 5 with 4.4.4):

[image]

This is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class InAppBrowserActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "URL";
    public static final int RESULT_FAILURE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webview);

        final String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Trying to load url " + url);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void closeActivity(int result){
        setResult(result);
        finish();
    }

    public class MyViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
           InAppBrowserActivity.this.closeActivity(RESULT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Sir Same problem I have Do you have any Solution.....For this...

Answer (score 0):

Set the viewport [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport?hl=en) suggestions

> < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I cannot configure those webpages as they belong to third party webs. I can only configure the parameters of the webview

Comment: Ok. Then can you check if this can perform as you desire: First, set the webview Layout to either `MATCH_PARENT` or any static value. then `webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false)`.... If that fails. then you need to intercept the requested page, and writte the viewport in the DOM. Google for code examples.

Comment: I does not work, I would prefer a solution other than modify the html content if possible. In fact it is working fine in the chrome navigator of the mobile.

Comment: Most browsers assume backwards compatibility, so if they do not detect a user agent, a viewport, or any other main guideline to show content, they assume a most generic one.... As you said, browsers can understand, but the emulator does not. This is because the native emulator is not a fully fledge system... You should assume that the incorrect behavior is undesired, and fix them. If you always show what you desire, then skip this as not an issue. Do note that EACH manufacturer can implement the system as they see fit, so, non-default behavior can change.

Answer (score 0):

you may try on this:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView .getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView .getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```